# Clicking row (with segue) of VC1 doesn't open VC2

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

Let's say I has a container view and inside it there is an UI View(Category Album View), a tableView to provide the data source to this UI View.

The problem is that when I click the row of "Category Album View", it doesn't open the following tableView, which is named "Album Name". I'm using segue id/`prepare()` to do the transfer, I check around my code, segue is set in `prepare()` in code and also in the storyboard. Any comment/hint is welcomed!

[image]

/ / / My code as below,

/ / / update my code, as vadian's comment, commenting `tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")` do fix the issue.

**CategoryAlbumView.swift**

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class CategoryAlbumView: UIViewController {

    var directoryContents = [URL]()
    var songName: String?
    var artistName: String?
    var albumName: String?
    var albumArtwork: UIImage?

    var tableData = [SongData]()
    var albumArray = [String]()



    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.retrieveSongsfromLocalDir()

        var seen = Set<String>()
        var unique = [SongData]()
        for message in tableData {
            if !seen.contains(message.albumName) {
                unique.append(message)
                seen.insert(message.albumName)
            }
        }

        // convert Set to Array
        albumArray = Array(seen)

        print("seen count", seen.count)

//        let testArray = tableData.filter { $0.albumName == "Beauty In The Mundane"}
//        print("TestArray count", testArray.count)

        // refresh table data.
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func retrieveSongsfromLocalDir() {
        do {
            tableData.removeAll()
            // Get the document directory url
            let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

            // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
            directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

            // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
            let mp3Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }

            // get music metadata (artist, album)
            for url in mp3Files {
                let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
                let metaData = asset.metadata

                // to use url's name for song name to avoid there is no metaData info for songs.
                let songTitle = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
                if songTitle != "" {
                    songName = songTitle
                } else {
                    songName = "Unknown Song"
                }

                if let artist = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyArtist}), let value = artist.value as? String {
                    artistName = value
                } else {
                    artistName = "Unknown Artist"
                }

                if let album = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyAlbumName}), let value = album.value as? String {
                    albumName = value
                    // print("Album:",albumName)
                } else {
                    albumName = "Unknown Album"
                }

                if let albumImage = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyArtwork}), let value = albumImage.value as? Data {
                    albumArtwork = UIImage(data: value)
                } else {
                    albumArtwork = UIImage(named: "Album-50")
                    print("artWork is not found!")
                }

                tableData.append(SongData(songName: songName!, artistName: artistName!, albumName: albumName!, albumArtwork: albumArtwork!, url: url))
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
}


extension CategoryAlbumView: UITableViewDelegate {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        switch segue.identifier {
            case "CategoryAlbumSongs":
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    let controller = segue.destination as! CategoryAlbumSongs
                    let cellText = albumArray[indexPath.row]
                    print("Prepare ========= Prepare ")
                    controller.albumSongs = tableData.filter { $0.albumName == cellText}
                }
            default: break

        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension CategoryAlbumView: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return albumArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = albumArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Album-50")

        return cell
    }
}
```

/ / / **CategoryAlbumSongs.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CategoryAlbumSongs: UITableViewController {

    var albumSongs = [SongData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return albumSongs.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = albumSongs[indexPath.row].songName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = albumSongs[indexPath.row].artistName
        cell.imageView?.image = albumSongs[indexPath.row].albumArtwork

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Check in `CategoryAlbumSongs` when is called `numberOfSections(in:)`, do `var albumsSongs: [SongData] = [] { didSet { print("didSetAlbumSongs"} }` . The order of the print (alongside your prepare one)?

Comment: Is the identifier `CategoryAlbumSongs` set properly. By the way I gave you repeatedly the advice **not** to get data from a table view cell. This is very bad practice. Don't do that. Get data always from the data source array (`albumArray`). And  you must not register table view cells if you are using prototype cells.

Comment: @vadian, it is the same identifier ```CategoryAlbumSongs``` in ```prepare()```as well as storyboard segue identifier. Err, that is really my bad to use data from table cell, bad habit, im sorry, change it now.

Comment: What does your implementation of `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)` look like ?

Comment: @Chris, I didn't use ```tableView(...didSelectRowAt...)``` because I'm using prepare() and segue then I don't need this function to deal with the row selection.

Comment: @Larme, I didn't get your point, mate. Do you mean to check ```numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView)```?

Comment: @vadian, just miss your word. comment this ```// tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")``` really fix the issue. Thus, does it mean if I register table view cells in the code, then shouldn't use prototype cell and to use static cell only in storyboard.

Comment: You need to register only if you are using cells in a XIB file

Comment: Where do you set `tableView.dataSource`?

Comment: Preferred in Interface Builder (although almost all tutorials suggest in code). Otherwise at the same place as setting the delegate.

Comment: @andrewbuilder, the dataSource of tableView is from ```albumArray``` and ```albumSongs```in my case, for root is from ```tableData``` array. Anyway this issue is solved per vadian's comment.

Comment: @ChuckZHB was intended as a leading question. My point - it is good practice to set `tableView.dataSource = self` at the same time you set `tableView.delegate = self`, either both in code, or both in and using IB. In your “update”, you set only `tableView.delegate = self` in code, in your `viewDdLoad` method. So my comment is relevant - where do you set `tableView.dataSource`? Maybe in IB? Either way, your answer is currently incomplete without that clarification.

Comment: @andrewbuilder, ```tableView.dataSource``` was set in IB via dragging the tableView to related VC. Well, I know what you mean now, better to set delegate and dataSource in same side.